# Generating a Stream of Aggregated elements from the given Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I am given a stream that produces a sequence of integers. I want to transform it into the stream of the aggregated sums.

E.g.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
```

Becomes:

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, ...
```

In general, I am looking for a stream operation (let's call it `aggregate`) that takes the same arguments as `reduce()` but it produces a stream of values instead of a single value. I imagine to use it roughly like this:

```
inputStream.aggregate(0, Integer::sum)
```

It would be even nicer if the output type could be different from the input type so that I could for example transform an initial state and a stream of operations to a stream of states.

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that source is an array an required result is collection of sums it might be done like that:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        
List<Integer> sums = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,  numbers.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(numbers, 0, i).sum())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sums);
```

*Output*

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
```

Comment: Couple of problems with that approach:
1. I don't want to make an assumption on what the source of the stream is.
2. It takes $O(n^2)$ steps while the aggregated sum could actually be calculated in $O(n)$.

Comment: @jederik In case if you didn't notice, I've provided [*another solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73583600/17949945) that runs in a linear time **O(n)** and can dial with any `Stream<T>`. If you have any questions, I would appreciate if you would express them without wanting three months.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a stream of integers, and you want to transform it into a stream where each element is a sum of all previous elements plus the current element (an element from the initial stream).

The first thing that we need to keep in mind is that to obtain such sequence transformation of each element requires incorporating the **state** of the previous element.

Tracking the previous element isn't a problem with loops. But while using streams, you need to be aware of API requirements regarding [*Stateless behavior*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) and [*Side-effects*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

There's **no** *clean way* to achieve the desired transformation of the stream.

But we can maintain a state while producing a value from the stream, i.e. we can generate a `Collection` containing the resulting sequence. And if you need a stream, then create a stream over this *collection*.

Then how it might be implemented using [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) (note that `reduce` that you've mentioned in the question isn't the right tool here, it's for so-called immutable reduction which into a folding the stream into a single value, not a collection of values):

```
List<Integer> aggregatedSequence = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    .collect(
        ArrayList::new,
        (List<Integer> list, Integer next) -> {
            if (list.isEmpty()) list.add(next);
            else list.add(list.get(list.size() - 1) + next);
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            right.replaceAll(i -> i + left.get(left.size() - 1));
            left.addAll(right);
        }
    );
    
aggregatedSequence.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
```

> It would be even nicer if the **output type** could be **different** from the **input type**

Sure, that's doable.

For that, you need to provide a *function* that would allow to map the elements of the initial stream to the resulting type, as well as a *function* responsible for merging values of the resulting (*since we're presumably no longer about numeric values we need other tool the plus operator*).

That method, transforming an initial stream of type `T` into an aggregated stream of type `R` might be implemented:

```
public static <T, R> Stream<R> getAggregatedStream(Stream<T> source,
                                                   Function<T, R> mapper,
                                                   BinaryOperator<R> mergeFunction) {
    return source.map(mapper)
        .collect(
            ArrayList::new,
            (List<R> list, R next) -> {
                if (list.isEmpty()) list.add(next);
                else list.add(mergeFunction.apply(list.get(list.size() - 1), next));
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                right.replaceAll(i -> mergeFunction.apply(left.get(left.size() - 1), i));
                left.addAll(right);
            }
        )
        .stream();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getAggregatedStream(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), String::valueOf, String::concat)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```